# Laravel 5.2 Auth Registration Redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to wrap the default Auth in `/en/wholesale/login`, but I am unable to submit a registration form. What file should I touch? currently it will just refresh the page.  instead of heading to RegistersUsers.php / register(Request $request).

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'web' ]
],
function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'wholesale'], function () {
        // Authentication Routes...
        Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
        Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
        Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
        Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

        // Password Reset Routes...
        Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
        Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
        Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    });

});
```

blade

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('wholesale/login') }}">
```

EDIT

I believe it have to do with

```
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
```

the app will still use the GET method instead of post on form submit.

EDIT 2

ok I solve the part of the question

```
action="{{ url('en/wholesale/register') }}"
```

I need to hardcode the 'en' part, in-order to route to the function, is there way that part can be route automatically?

Comment: show us the full form and the controller and explain more the probleme pls

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja please see the 2nd EDIT, all the controller is the default one that come with `php artisan make:auth` I only posted the part that I change.

Comment: Have you fix this? i got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

if you use default authentication from Laravel you can see `router.php` file as all login and registration route are registered there and you can call them in your routes.php file with `Route::auth()`. you might want to see `AuthenticatesUsers` or `RegistersUsers` traits as authController.php use `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait to config your authentication. hope it helps.